# python equivalent T-SQL format (hashing)

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, hash

How to hash in python an equivalent of the following (changing the sql part isn't possible, only to mimic the behavior in python):

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', FORMAT(1234, ''))
```

```
output: 0x4F37C061F1854F9682F543FECB5EE9D652C803235970202DE97C6E40C8361766
```

which is different than:

```sql
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','1234')
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CAST(1234 as VARCHAR(100)))
```

```
output: 0x03AC674216F3E15C761EE1A5E255F067953623C8B388B4459E13F978D7C846F4
```

How to achieve in python the first output? Currently:

```py
from hashlib import sha256

sha256('1234'.encode()).hexdigest().upper()
```

```
output: 03AC674216F3E15C761EE1A5E255F067953623C8B388B4459E13F978D7C846F4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Format( 1234, '' )` is an `NVarChar`:

```
select sql_variant_property(FORMAT(1234, ''), 'basetype');
```

You can `cast` the value to get the desired result:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',CAST(FORMAT(1234, '') as VARCHAR(100)));
```

Comment: thanks, I know, but as I said: `changing the sql part isn't possible`

Comment: @NunoSilva That would mean changing the snake code to have wider characters, no?

Comment: thanks good point. ok, will look into that. from the top of you head you know how to do it?

Comment: @NunoSilva `sha256('1234'.encode("utf-16")[2:]).hexdigest().upper()` seems to take care of a two-byte prefix that `encode` is adding.

Comment: it solves it, same result as sql hash with format output. thanks @HABO,